# ASP C# - logoutaction redirect not working

Tags: asp.net, logout, loginstatus

loginstatus control on my SiteMaster
if I select properties, i can choose:
LogoutAction, selected redirect
LogOutPageURL, selected my logoutpage

" LogoutText="<%$ Resources:Global, SignOut %>" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/LogoutPage.aspx" OnLoggingOut="loginStatus_LoggingOut" />

When I logout, it takes me right back to my default sign in page and not my logoutpage.

I've set an execption so anyone can hit logout page, and I can hit the logoutpage successfully.

For whatever reason though that loginstatus control will not redirect to my logoutpageurl?

Any thoughts on what would cause this?
Does the web.config LoginUrl override the above?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, I had two lines of code for two different menu options for sign out.

Also note, in my investgation I found the full path necessary:
LogoutPageUrl="~/LogoutPage.aspx"